# E-mail verification in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using register-plus plugin for registration purpose in my wordpress site. I have enalbled E-mail verifiacation whereby user will be getting an activation link. What i want to do is when the user clicks the link, i want the user to be enabled automatically.......currently admin has to login to the system and verify the users for the new user to login.....how do i achieve my task ...ANy help is appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is *Admin Verification (Moderate all user registrations to require admin approval)* enabled in the plugin options? If yes, disable it.

Comment: its disabled......but i cant make the user enable automatically once he/she clicks the link...... Admin needs to enable him/her. What do i do

Comment: I don't understand. I just checked again and ran a small test. If *Admin Verification* is disabled, after the user visits the link provided in the email, they can login without further approval. Something else must be wrong. After going to the verification link, do you still see the user in the *Unverified Users* list?

Comment: So: 1. You have enabled *Anyone can register* in the Settings > General page and 2. When you receive the email and click the link, the user doesn't become active? Very important (since it's the only thing I can think of right now): have you actually clicked on a verification link and it didn't work?

Comment: yes...i clicked on the link......and tried loggin in....dint work out....wen i checked wp_users table, user_login field was still having unverified_343243234 value instead of username

Comment: Then I'm completely lost. The user_login field should change automatically after you visit the verification link. It's like the update in the database isn't done correctly. Sorry, I don't have any more suggestions.